# Reading int16 from binary file in Golang

Tags: go, binary

I'm currently working on a Golang program which reads a 16-bit integer from stdin. I am expecting a value of between 3 and ~128, however, when I print out the integer value it is completely random, going from 30,000+ to -30,000.

I am doing the same thing in PHP by doing the following:

```
<?php

$binary = fread($stream, 2);
$unpacked = unpack('s', $binary);
$int = reset($unpacked);
```

This works successfully. The Go code that I am working on is located on GitHub here: https://github.com/uniquoooo/dca/blob/decoding/main.go#L502-L536

I'm using bash pipes (e.g. `cat testfile | command`) to pipe the contents into the program.

Here is some testing Golang code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/binary"
    "io"
    "os"

    "github.com/layeh/gopus"
)

func main() {
    OpusDecoder, err := gopus.NewDecoder(48000, 2)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _ = OpusDecoder

    dcabuf := bufio.NewReaderSize(os.Stdin, 16384)

    var opuslen uint16

    for {
        err = binary.Read(dcabuf, binary.LittleEndian, &opuslen)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF || err == io.ErrUnexpectedEOF {
                return
            }
            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("Frame Size:", opuslen)

        opus := make([]byte, opuslen)
        err = binary.Read(dcabuf, binary.LittleEndian, &opus)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF || err == io.ErrUnexpectedEOF {
                return
            }
            panic(err)
        }

        // pcm, err := OpusDecoder.Decode(opus, 1920, false)
        // if err != nil {
        //     panic(err)
        // }

        // err = binary.Write(os.Stdout, binary.LittleEndian, &pcm)
        // if err != nil {
        //     if err == io.EOF || err == io.ErrUnexpectedEOF {
        //         return
        //     }
        //     panic(err)
        // }
    }
}
```

I would expect output to be similar to `Frame Size: 128` but the value is a lot higher.

I have uploaded a test file on my Google Drive here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_559nfSNrcfMUNhbWdJMGptZGs/view?usp=sharing

To run the program, build it with `go build` and then run like this:

```
cat test.dca | ./main
```

The executable name may be different.

Comment: can you add  sample file with values?

Comment: You haven't provided us with a reproducible error: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sounds like you're getting byte numbers from a string-type. But as peter says; can only tell if there's more information.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've added some example code and a sample file. @msingh

Comment: in case you're looking for a library that can read opus audio files and streams directly, I wrote one that does just that; https://github.com/hraban/opus. It will take care of this for you.

Comment: Shouldn't you be storing your PCM frames into `int16` rather than `uint16`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are getting encoded bytes. In other words, 1 is becoming 49, etc (depends on the encoding). The way around this is to normalize the byte back to the represented value (e.g. byte-'0') for each byte within the int16.

a possible way you could do this is

```
a := uint16(((opuslen & 0xff00) >> 8) - '0')
b := uint16((opuslen & 0x00ff) - '0')
opuslen = (function to splice together)
```

Though this is a chore, this is what you'd have to do to ensure bytes are not maintaining their encoding. That, or just don't store as a utf/ascii/whatever encoded value. would look funky to a human when cat-ing it, but yeah who cares :)

You'll also notice I changed opuslen to uint just for ease of demonstration. if you expect negative length (to denote compression maybe?) then adjust as needed.

Edit: 
If you truly are going to be working with encoded bytes, perhaps you should read into a string and use strconv.Atoi, which would make it easier for you since you wouldn't have to write the code yourself to convert.